# Test and publish workflows conditionally running

Tags: git, github-actions

I want to launch the `unittest` workflow on every push/pull request. Then I want to run the `publish` workflow only if `unittest` succeeded and on new tags.

This is some basic git flow management but it seems GitHub Actions doesn't really want developers to do that.

This is what I have:

```
# unittest.yml

name: Unittest
on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  unit-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    ...
```

```
# publish.yml

name: Publish
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [Unittest]
    types: [completed]
    branches:
      - 'releases/**'

jobs:
  publish-image:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    ...
```

The two workflows have been tested and are working. Whenever I push a new tag `unittest` is launched, passed with success but `publish` isn't.

I looked in the docs [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run) and [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onworkflow_runbranchesbranches-ignore).

Any suggestions?

Comment: _"isn't"_ what - what's happening? Why not just trigger `publish` _from_ `unittest`?

Comment: I'm not against that, do you have a solution to trigger publish only when a tag is pushed? And make unittest running everytime?

Comment: Same way you'd make any other step or job conditional: `if`. E.g. https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/blob/1e4a2f9cc4df2ba2594ad22b566d611af26a47a8/.github/workflows/push.yml#L58-L59

Comment: Nice will give a try, didn't find that github in any official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In regard to your original attempt using `workflow_run` to trigger `publish`, **it does not appear to be possible with the standard syntax to limit `workflow_run` triggers to tag-push events**. The better solution is to use a conditional within the same workflow.

The issue is that the `workflow_run` event only supports the `branches` and `branches-ignore` filters, but does not support the `tags` or `tags-ignore` filters. Using only the `branches` or `branches-ignore` filter will prevent the workflow from running on `tag` events.

For completeness, this is how you would adjust the original `publish` workflow to only trigger after a **successful** run of the `unittest` workflow, but it would run on both the `tag` and `branch` push events (as well as `pull_request`):

```yaml
name: Publish
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [Unittest]
    types: [completed]

jobs:
  publish-image:
    if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    ...
```